# How to integrate an already existing login script into a new login form present on every page?

Tags: php, forms, session, authentication

Couple weeks ago i integrated an open-source file admnistrator to my website which included a login/member system. (file admnistrator can be found [here](http://www.geraudlacheny.fr/un-explorateur-de-fichiers-php/)).

Since i'm learning web developping i thought this would be a great idea to integrate this login system to my whole website. 
So i added the necessary php code to stay connected in my header (included on every page), and a logout script wasn't a problem neither.

But my problem is with the login form. Here is the one i made (it is in my header.php file) :

```
<form method="post" action="">

        <div id="username">
            <input type="text" name="txt_username" id="txt_username" placeholder="username" required="" value="" />
        <span class="username_icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div id="password">
        <input type="password" name="txt_password" id="txt_password" placeholder="password" required="" />
        <span class="password_icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div id="stay_connected">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk_connected" id="chk_connected"> 
        <label for="chk_connected"><span>Stay Connected</span></label>
        </div>
        <div id="submit_button">
        <button type="submit" name="sub_login" id="sub_login"><i id="submit"class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="feedback">login successful <br />redirecting...</div>

        </form>
```

and here is the original full login.php that the file admnistrator uses to login his users (which i intend to kick out once mine is ready) :

```
<?php 

require_once('config/config.inc.php');
require_once('config/settings.inc.php');
require_once('classes/User.php');
require_once('lib/functions.php');

session_start();

/***********************************************************************************************************/
/********************************* INITIALISATION OF VARIABLES ********************************************/
/***********************************************************************************************************/
$error = "";

/***********************************************************************************************************/
/********************************* DATA TREATMENT **************************************************/
/***********************************************************************************************************/
if(isset($_COOKIE['identifiant']) && !empty($_COOKIE['identifiant']) && isset($_COOKIE['mdp']) && !empty($_COOKIE['mdp'])) {


    $monUtilisateur = User::check($_COOKIE['identifiant'], $_COOKIE['mdp']);

    if($monUtilisateur !== false) {
        $_SESSION['auth'] = $monUtilisateur;
        redirect('index.php');
    }
    else {
        // on supprime les cookies
        setcookie('identifiant');
        setcookie('mdp');

        $error = "The username or password is incorrect.";  
    }

}
else {

    if( isset($_POST['txt_identifiant']) || isset($_POST['txt_mdp']) ) {

        /////////// PRELIMINARY CONTROLS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $nbErreurs = isset($GLOBALS['login_nbErreurs']) ? (int)$GLOBALS['login_nbErreurs'] : 0;
        $nbChampsrestantsaremplir = isset($GLOBALS['login_nbChampsrestantsaremplir']) ? (int)$GLOBALS['login_nbChampsrestantsaremplir'] : 0;
        $t_erreurs = array();

        /***********************************************************************************************************/
        /********** USERNAME ************************************************************************************/
        /***********************************************************************************************************/
        if (isset($_POST['txt_identifiant'])) {
            $_POST['txt_identifiant'] = trim($_POST['txt_identifiant']);
            if ($_POST['txt_identifiant'] == '') {
                $nbChampsrestantsaremplir++;
                $t_erreurs['txt_identifiant'] = 'Veuillez saisir votre identifiant';
            }
        }

        /***********************************************************************************************************/
        /*********** PASSWORD *******************************************************************************************/
        /***********************************************************************************************************/
        if (isset($_POST['txt_mdp'])) {
            $_POST['txt_mdp'] = trim($_POST['txt_mdp']);
            if ($_POST['txt_mdp'] == '') {
                $nbChampsrestantsaremplir++;
                $t_erreurs['txt_mdp'] = 'Please enter your password';
            }
        }

        ////////// END OF PRELIMINARY CONTROLS //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $GLOBALS['login_nbErreurs'] = $nbErreurs;
        $GLOBALS['login_nbChampsrestantsaremplir'] = $nbChampsrestantsaremplir ;


        if ($nbErreurs == 0 && $nbChampsrestantsaremplir == 0) {

            $monUtilisateur = User::check($_POST['txt_identifiant'], $_POST['txt_mdp']);

            if($monUtilisateur !== false) {
                // si l'authentification est bonne et que la case est cochee, on cree le cookie
                if (isset($_POST['chk_cookie']) && $_POST['chk_cookie']=="oui") {           
                    // on cree les cookies valide 1 JOUR            
                    setcookie('identifiant', $_POST['txt_identifiant'], time() + 1*24*3600, null, null, false, true);
                    setcookie('mdp', $_POST['txt_mdp'], time() + 1*24*3600, null, null, false, true);
                }
                // sinon on supprime
                else {
                    // on supprime les cookies  
                    setcookie('identifiant');
                    setcookie('mdp');
                }
                //je cree une session
                $_SESSION['auth'] = $monUtilisateur;

                //je redirige
                redirect('index.php');
            }
            else 
                $error = "The username or password is incorrect.";

        }

    }

}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Authentification</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/original/css/login.css" />

    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- SCRIPTS DIVERS -->
    <script src="js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[placeholder]').placeholder();
    });
    </script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('#txt_identifiant').focus();                                  
    }); 
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="content">

        <div id="logo">
            <img alt="logo" src="themes/original/images/logo.png" />
        </div>

        <? if(isset($error)) { ?><p class="error"><?php echo $error ?></p><? } ?>

        <form method="post" action="login.php">

            <div id="identifiant">
                <input type="text" name="txt_identifiant" id="txt_identifiant" placeholder="Identifiant" required="" value="" />
            </div>
            <div id="mdp">
                <input type="password" name="txt_mdp" id="txt_mdp" placeholder="Mot de passe" required="" />
            </div>
            <div id="maintenir">
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk_maintenir" id="chk_maintenir"> 
                <label for="chk_maintenir"><span>Stay connected</span></label>
            </div>
            <div id="soumettre">
                <input type="submit" name="sub_login" id="sub_login" value="Connexion" style="width:100px;" />
            </div>

        </form>

</div><!-- fin de content -->

</body>
</html>
```

I naively tried to implement the php code present on the original login.php (while changing the paths) but of course it didn't do the trick. And even if it did i wasn't sure this was actually the best idea.
I feel like having all the login php code in my header would be kind of "heavy" or maybe poor structuration.

For instance the logout system is pretty easy, a button that redirects that leads to the logout.php page which then instantly destroy the session and redirect the user where i want to.
This is more or less what i was trying to do with the login system : submit the form -> brieflycall for a login.php file that checks if everything is allright and start the session -> redirect to the page instantly.

But so far, using the original code of the file admnistrator's login page and my poor knowledges i haven't been able to do that.

Hopefully i'm clear enough, i'm pretty new at all this, but i'm willing to follow every instructions and try your suggestions the best i can !

Thanks a lot for your help,

-Apatik

> > > Resolved thanks to Julios, check the comments. Thanks !

Comment: just change the name of your form fields to match the ones on your colleague's form. like changing this:  `<input type="text" name="txt_username" id="txt_username" placeholder="username" required="" value="" />` to `<input type="text" name="txt_identifiant" id="txt_identifiant" placeholder="username" required="" value="" />`. change for all input elements and it shoud make it work.

Comment: Although you might want to google **xss attacks** before taking in your hands the responsibility for submitting forms with user data to your server...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yeah i totally forgot about this, i will actually change his part rather than mine so it's in "english" and where also where the function is called. But how can i have my submit button redirect to this login.php file and then "check" the fields ? I'll have to delete the login form of his login.php also since i already got one on my header. thanks for the help !

Comment: (to your second comment: checking up that right now)

Comment: check the action attribute in his form `action="login.php"`  and use the same in your's

Comment: I will do that and update, thanks. Regarding your previous answer i checked theses attacks but i'm a rookie in web programming. What this means is that transfering data entered by a user to another page can causes issues cause he could type some malicious code to attack the website ? What if i set a code that checks if the input is letters string only ? Thanks

Comment: Hum there is no action="login.php" unfortunately in his code. His php code that collects the data is in the same page as his form. Did i miss something ?

Comment: It means one can fake a submition to your login.php (in a very similar way you are going to do by reproducing hte input fields) So "I" could, for instance, lure a user to use my login form instead of your's. Then I could get his username and password, and then post his request to your real login.php.
As he would succeed login in, he wouldn't even notice I've have stollen his username/password. Then I could get access to your system and try to find more weak spots.., or just try to login on his paypal... chances are it's the same user/pwd

Comment: It's right there in the html you posted as his code... `<form method="post" action="login.php">`

Comment: That works ! Awesome. I put the thread as resolved thanks a lot ! I have an another question tho, regarding what you said before. So basically you advice me not to do what we just did ? That i should include his php code that checks the input and start the session in my header where the form is ? Ot is there a way to "secure" the method you just helped me with ? Thanks again (edit: doesn't seem like a i can approve your answer since it's in the comments ?)

Comment: Minimally we can put a hidden field in any form we present to the user. In the hidden field value attribute we place a random value that we keep in $_SESSION for a single use (change on every get and after consuming any post). If we receive a post from a form we check if the value of the hidden field matches the value stored in $_SESSION. If the values match proceed with login (in this example) as teh user is using your real form. If not... send the user to the homepage without further explanation.

Comment: Green ticks welcome!

Comment: Allright, thanks that was helpful. I will finish optimizing my login php file and then definitely look into that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make you form elements name and form action match the names and action of the original login form.